# Chrome DevTools (sometimes) displays empty file source

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Sometimes in Chrome DevTools, a file source will display as a blank source:

[image]

[image]

The visual content will exist in the browser, but some of the scripts will have not executed, including network requests for other scripts (like analytics files).

Most of the time this doesn't happen and the source file shows all content as expected. I'm wondering if this could simply be a Chrome bug of some sort?